# Scrapy: Extracting data from JSON response embedded in HTML

Tags: json, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm currently trying to extract the publishing date hidden in a JSON response embedded in HTML while using scrapy.

The HTML looks like this:

```
</div>
    <div class="review-content-header__dates">
        
<script type="application/json" data-initial-state="review-dates">
{"publishedDate":"2020-06-19T12:10:39Z","updatedDate":null,"reportedDate":null}
</script>

<review-dates
    :published-date="publishedDate"
    :reported-date="reportedDate"
    :updated-date="updatedDate"
></review-dates>
    </div>
```

I want to collect the date within this JSON response: `{"publishedDate":"2020-06-19T12:10:39Z","updatedDate":null,"reportedDate":null}`

Meaning the result should look like this: `"2020-06-01T17:39:19Z"`.

It took me a while to figure out that although the information is displayed on the page I can't really access it with css or xpath selectors. Currently I see only two solutions:

1. Using this `response.css('div.review-content-header__dates').get()` and grab everything. This would be the result:

```
'<div class="review-content-header__dates">\n        \n<script type="application/json" data-initial-state="review-dates">\n{"publishedDate":"2020-06-19T12:10:39Z","updatedDate":null,"reportedDate":null}\n</script>\n\n<review-dates :published-date="publishedDate" :reported-date="reportedDate" :updated-date="updatedDate"></review-dates>\n    </div>'
```

I would then use regex to somehow get the date (I wasn't able to manage this so far).

2. Finding a way to extract the data from the JSON. I did some research but couldn't find a solution that worked for me.

I would be glad if you could leave your thoughts on this issue. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the JSON content using e.g. XPath and the use `json.loads` to get the content as dict. Here's a demo:

```
import json
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

response = HtmlResponse(url='dummy.org', encoding='utf-8', body="""
</div>
    <div class="review-content-header__dates">
        
    <script type="application/json" data-initial-state="review-dates">
    {"publishedDate":"2020-06-19T12:10:39Z","updatedDate":null,"reportedDate":null}
    </script>

    <review-dates
        :published-date="publishedDate"
        :reported-date="reportedDate"
        :updated-date="updatedDate"
    ></review-dates>
</div>""")

content = response.xpath('//script[@data-initial-state]/text()').get()
data = json.loads(content)

print(data['publishedDate'])
```

It will print `2020-06-19T12:10:39Z`.

You can achieve the same using regex, e.g.:

```
response.xpath('//script[@data-initial-state]/text()').re_first(r'"publishedDate":\s*"([^"]+)"')
```

but the former solution is cleaner in my opinion.